# Homology commutes with direct sum and product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm looking at exercise 1.2.1 from Weibel's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*. (I need to show that homology commutes with direct sum and direct product.)

> Is it possible to show that cokernels commute with direct sum and product?

Since $H_{n} (C)=\ker d_{n}/ \operatorname{im} d_{n+1}$, $H_{n} (C)=\operatorname{coker} d'_{n+1},$ where $d'_{n+1}:C_{n+1}\rightarrow \ker d_{n}\subset C_{n}$.

> Or, if I can show that kernels, images, and quotients commute with direct sums and products, would that also prove the statement?

I can start with $\oplus(\ker d_{n})=\ker(\oplus d_{n})$, $\oplus(\operatorname{im} d_{n+1})= \operatorname{im}(\oplus d_{n+1})$, then $\oplus (\ker d_n /\operatorname{im} d_{n+1})=\ker \oplus d_n / \operatorname{im}\oplus d_{n+1}$ or $\oplus \ H_n (C)=H_n (\oplus \ C)$ where $ \oplus \ d$ is the differential for the chain complex $\oplus \ C. $ Similar statements for direct product. So my questions are, is it true that quotients, image, and kernel commute with direct sum and product? I think its easy to see that image and kernel commute with direct sum and product but I don't know how to prove it. I'm not so sure about quotients.

Comment: Any additive functor preserves finite direct sums/products. In particular, both cokernels and kernels (hence also images and quotients) commute with finite direct sums/products.

Comment: The exercise said prove it for all n (so finite.) Would it also be true for infinite direct sums and products?

Comment: @010110111 the exercise only asks to prove that the functor $H_n$ for all $n$ commutes with any type (finite or infinite) sums and products. So yes it is true for infinite type too, provided that the category satisfies AB4 or AB4* respectively

Answer (score 11):

it is just a basic computation:

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to write this in TeX. We don't want nobody breaking their neck by trying to look at this.

Answer (score 8):

To treat exercise 1.2.1 in the most general setup, you can say that in a category in which colimits exists and the direct product functor is exact (AB4 type category), the homology functor of any degree does commute with direct sum.
The proof is simple: take the following exact sequence $$0\to \text{im}\ d_{n+1}\to \ker d_{n}\to H_n(A_n^{i})\to 0$$ where $A^{i}$ is a complex for $i\in I$. Apply the exact functor direct sum. You immediately get what you want since by exactness direct sum commutes with $\ker$ (AB4) and $\text{im}$ (always).

For direct product everything dualises well (if the category verifies AB4*)